# Difference between Volume Disk Space and Disk usage returned by ncdu

Tags: disk-space-utilization, df

My server has a 130 GB Volume attached.

To check the free disk psace, I run `df -h -x tmpfs -x squashfs | grep -v /run/shared` and I get :

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            965M     0  965M   0% /dev
/dev/xvda1      128G  111G   13G  90% /
```

However, when I want the details of the disk usage, by running `ncdu` on the root directory, I get :

```
.  55,7 GiB [######### ] /home                                                                                                                           
.  24,0 GiB [####      ] /var
.   2,4 GiB [          ] /usr
    1,0 GiB [          ]  swapfile
  598,6 MiB [          ] /lib
   63,0 MiB [          ] /boot
    9,4 MiB [          ] /sbin
    9,1 MiB [          ] /bin
.   8,1 MiB [          ] /etc
.   4,3 MiB [          ] /tmp
.   2,7 MiB [          ] /run
!  24,0 KiB [          ] /root
!  16,0 KiB [          ] /lost+found
    4,0 KiB [          ] /lib64
e   4,0 KiB [          ] /opt
e   4,0 KiB [          ] /mnt
e   4,0 KiB [          ] /media
!   4,0 KiB [          ] /gandi
.   0,0   B [          ] /proc
.   0,0   B [          ] /sys
    0,0   B [          ] /dev
@   0,0   B [          ]  initrd.img.old
@   0,0   B [          ]  initrd.img
@   0,0   B [          ]  vmlinuz.old
@   0,0   B [          ]  vmlinuz
e   0,0   B [          ] /srv
```

There is a difference of about 27 GB with the free disk space returned by the previous command (111 GB).

Where does this difference come from ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This question comes up quite often. The short answer is `du` and `df` use differect methods to get data.

> The file system allocates disk blocks in the file system to record its data. This data is referred to as metadata which is not visible to most user-level programs (such as du). Examples of metadata are inodes, disk maps, indirect blocks, and superblocks.

> The **du** command is a user-level program that isn't aware of filesystem metadata, while df looks at the filesystem disk allocation maps and is aware of file system metadata.  **df** obtains true filesystem statistics, whereas du sees only a partial picture.

Comment: Thanks @4snok. I also have another difference between the calculation made by `ncdu` and a calculation made with PHP with the Flysystem package ?